# Merge multiple lines between same pattern into a single line using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some log files with some information as below

```
2016-03-18 00:07:43,482 SOME ERROR 
OCCURED
API 
LINE INFO
2016-03-18 00:07:44,482 OCCURED
authentication failure
2016-03-18 00:07:45,482 ERROR OCCURED
2016-03-18 00:07:46,482 NOT IMP OCCURED
```

**Desired Output**

```
2016-03-18 00:07:43,482 SOME ERROR OCCURED API LINE INFO
2016-03-18 00:07:44,482 OCCURED authentication failure
2016-03-18 00:07:45,482 ERROR OCCURED
2016-03-18 00:07:46,482 NOT IMP OCCURED
```

That means I want to merge all the lines between 2016-03-18

I want every line to start with the 2016-03-18 as the pattern.

Could someone help me do this using shell scripting preferably using awk/Sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '
    /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && line {print line; line=""}
    {line = line ? line" "$0 : $0}
    END {print line}
' file
```

---

**Update**

It turned out that some `awk` implementations doesn't support `{n}` quantifiers. For example `mawk`.

In that case you'll have to write the command like this:

```
mawk '
    /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/ && line {print line; line=""}
    {line = line ? line" "$0 : $0}
    END {print line}
' file
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. i have used this awk '    /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ && line {print line; line=""}    {line = line ? line" "$0 : $0}    END {print line}' tt.txt >tt1.txt

Comment: @JavaTechy Looks like your implementation of `awk` does not support `{n}` quantifiers. I've added a workaround.

Comment: this is also not working.I am new to awk. I think this can help u. This question is similar . but i dont know what to change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099468/how-to-merge-unknown-number-of-multiple-lines-between-two-patterns-into-a-single

Comment: Being new to something is not a problem but also no excuse. "this is also not working" is not a helpful error report. I obviously can't jump into your computer and check what is "not working". What is your awk version?

Comment: Don't get angry. Its fine. i will try more into it. thanks for the help. its 1.3.3

Comment: Again, what is your awk version?

Comment: this is the version mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

Comment: Hmm, the second example I gave has been explicitly tested against that version. Are you using the sample data from the question or something different?

Comment: the data is same. the only difference is  that i am writing output to a file and then checking it. And in command line also the result is same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106794/discussion-between-javatechy-and-hek2mgl).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n....-..-.. /!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if the second line does not match the pattern that starts a line replace its preceeding newline by a space and repeat. Otherwise print and then delete the first line and repeat.